# How does single query multiple answer database works in a query website

Tags: php, mysql

According to **MySQL** database, in a table there will be fixed number of columns and each row will be assigned to each question posted.

Lets say for example, we have 3 column table of which ID, Question, Answer are the labels.
And when it comes to multi answering system, where does the second answer is stored?

Is there an auto column creation script for **PHP** or **MYSQL**?

Explanation along with example is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add extra columns but his is totally wrong because it is not normalized instead you create 2 tables.

1. Question
2. Answers

The Questions only two columns

1. Id
2. question

The Answers has 3 columns

1. Id
2. Answer
3. question_id

and when you have a new answer then you just insert it into the Answer table. You link it with the question by the question_id column.

Comment: But what about multiple answers... ? say we got two questions. .   table #1 referws to ID#1-quetion#1 and ID#2-question#2..... then in table #2:: ID#1-Answer#1-Qestion_ID#1 and ID#2-Answer#2-Qestion_ID#2 ..... now what about extra answer to question 1. where it will be stored?

Comment: This is the way how you solve the multiple answer problem. You just insert answer in the answer table but you insert the question_id too and you can use it to define which answer belongs to which question. Id doesn't matter how many questions or answers you have

Comment: if the answer is correct mark it

Comment: Can you take a look on this one man... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db